# Why does Clearcase diffbl include activities from my development stream when I diff integration stream baselines?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are using Clearcase UCM and have one Integration stream and each developer has a development stream.  When I do a baseline compare, activities from the development stream are sometimes included.   Is there any way to get a simple list of activities in the integration stream since a particular baseline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: in the integration stream, you will mostly get deliver activities, ie activities recording the merges done during delivers from the development stream.

So if you want activities from two baselines done on the integration Stream, a simple

```
cleartool diffbl -nmerge -act bl1 bl2
```

should be enough.
If you somehow see activities from the development stream, that should mean you are comparing `bl1` from integration stream with `bl2` from a development stream or two baselines from integration with merges, ie with contributing activities.

Hence the `–nmerge`

> Compares two baselines on the same stream and reports only activity and version changes made on that stream.

---

To illustrate why you see those activities without the -nmerge, see "[List the contributing activities in the change set of a baseline or an integration activity](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21128235)"

An activity from the integration Stream will look like this:

[image: integration activity]

> Integration activities track work completed as a result of a deliver or rebase operation, and they are named accordingly with a prefix of either deliver or rebase to help distinguish them from user created activities.

If you right-click the activity and select Show Contributing Activities, you will see:

[image: contributing activity]

Which is the same than:

```
 cleartool lsactivity -contrib <deliver baseline>@\pvob
```

or

```
 cleartool lsact -fmt "%[contrib_acts]p" <deliver baseline>@\pvob
```

Again, the `-nmerge` option avoids the `diffbl` to list those contributing activities.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Somehow this very simple option escaped my knowledge.  This worked exactly as I need.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the contributing activities that come from child streams... Try

> diffbl -nmerge