# How to retrieve the list of files modified in same branch for different component in clear case

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I need to retrieve the list of changes or activity in same branch for different component(or Project group). Say I am committing the changes for two components ABC & xyz in same branch. And whenever I create build I apply the label abc.00.date & xyz.00.date respectively. Now major CQ's are of abc so whenever I make build for xyz and apply lable, label attach to abc chnages and when I compare the baseline with comapre tool, it shows the chnages of abc project also.

My requirement is to get the changes between label of xyz.00.date  group ONLY as there is numerous lables of two groups in same branch.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to retrieve the list of changes or activity in same branch for different component

The main command remains [`cleartool lsactivity`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-8), as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14089291/6309):

```
foreach act ( `cleartool lsact -in astream@/vobs/avob` )    
    set changeset = `cleartool lsact -fmt "%[versions]p" $act`
    echo $changeset | tr ' ' '\n' >> $tmpoutput
end
```

For the difference between baselines, use [`cleartool diffbl`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-7), as in "[Why does Clearcase diffbl include activities from my development stream when I diff integration stream baselines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626657/6309)"

```
cleartool diffbl -nmerge -act bl1 bl2
```

That will give you a list of activities that you can feed to the foreach loop above, modified as:

```
foreach act ( `cleartool diffbl -nmerge -act bl1 bl2` )
```

---

On Windows, those unix commands are available with the installation of [Gnu On Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/releases): uncompress, and add `GoW\bin` to your `%PATH%`.

Comment: thanks @vonc, but where I supposed to write the above code or this is a one line command ?

Comment: @R.Sha it is a bash script.

Comment: ok @vonc, but I am unable to find where would I put two baselines into which i have to see the difference like xyz.00.0101 and xyz.00.0102.

Comment: @R.Sha I have edited the answer to ad the diffbl part.

Comment: Thanks @vonc, I am about to reach at my goal, but a little confusion here in 2nd line of code above, what this "%[versions]p" versions refer here.

Comment: @R.Sha it refers to `fmt_ccase`: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-6-6

Comment: @R.Sha Don't forget to revisit your previous question and accet the ones that are resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: can we achieve the same in batch file instead of bash as I am on windows platform

Comment: @R.Sha First, don't forget to revisit your previous question and accet the ones that are resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer